# android dictionary int, Imageview

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I am failing to put objects in dictionary and get them, I want to put imageViews against int but failing without any error

dictionary declared as:

```
    Dictionary<Integer, ImageView> dictPlayerAll = new Dictionary<Integer, ImageView>(){

        @Override
        public int size() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public ImageView remove(Object key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ImageView put(Integer key, ImageView value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<Integer> keys() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public ImageView get(Object key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<ImageView> elements() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };;
```

here putting values in dictionary

```
    int mTag = iv.getTag();//its my imageview
    dictPlayerAll.put(mTag, iv);
```

but it shows zero size

Comment: Do you use setTag() anywhere? I would use `int mTag = iv.getId();`

Comment: yes i have settag() where i am using this imageview

Comment: "it shows zero size" becaue you `return 0;`, Don't implement a `Dictionary` yourself, use an implementation of that like `Hashtable` or better `HashMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update makes more sense, but the Dictionary class is still obselete. From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary.html):

> **java.util
>   Class Dictionary**
>   ...
>   Note: Do not use this class since it is obsolete.

Since you want to create a table indexed by Integers (`new Dictionary<Integer, ImageView>()`) we should use a SparseArray.

Also when you use `setTag()` you convert your Integer to an Object and every time you use `getTag()` you are converting your Integer back from an Object. This works, but if you can use `getId()` it will be faster.

I recommend this:

```
SparseArray<ImageView> allPlayers = new SparseArray<ImageView>();
...

allPlayers.put(iv.getId(), iv);
```

Comment: yeah great it worked according to my need , i am new to java i didn't know that its obselete in java, many thanks

Comment: Instead of :
SparseArray<ImageView> allPlayers = new SparseArray<ImageView>();
You need to to:
SparseArray<ImageView> allPlayers = new SparseArray<>();